# FC-SAN: How can I know there is new disk adding to the SAN?

Tags: linux, scsi, san, fc

If there is a SAN like this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMpW2.png) . when a new storage adds to the SAN, as a host how can I see it? whether it will be listed in the 'lsscsi' command ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. Unix & Linux or Super User would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely, you are struggling to send LIP - Loop initialization primitive. Read this [post](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/when-to-use-rescan-scsi-bus-sh-i-lip-flag-in-centos-rhel/) , for example, how to issue it.

Note, **this procedure blocks IO**, so be very careful doing it in production.